# Meaning of pods 110 in resources

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernetes documentation I haven't found any explanation of the pods line when describing resources:

[image]

What does "pods 110" mean? Why is it fixed to 110?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) documentation:

```
--max-pods int32     Default: 110
Number of Pods that can run on this Kubelet.
```

So, that means that 110 pods could be created on node by default.